Figuring out dimensional modeling requirements for OLAP in a database containing many pre-aggregated fact tables
I have the situation where we have an application that uses a PostgreSQL database for OLAP queries for reporting (less DWH/exploratory). I am trying to find an optimal database design for this workload.
The initial incoming transaction data is preaggregated using an ETL pipeline and aggregations for different dimensions are streamed into 'per-aggregation' fact tables where each deals with slightly different dimensions.
The requirements for this ETL Pipeline is to be near-realtime and as such something like a DWH with a nighly batch refresh of a single fact table with a star/snowflake schema was unfortunately not an option .
These pre-aggregated fact tables looks as follows:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hourly_revenue
(
    hour TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
    outlet_id UUID,
    gross_revenue NUMERIC(18,3),
    net_revenue NUMERIC(18,3),
    PRIMARY KEY (outlet_id, hour)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hourly_article_revenue
(
    article_group_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    article_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    hour timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL,
    plu character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    outlet_id uuid NOT NULL,
    base_price numeric(18,3),
    line_totals numeric(18,3),
    sum_quantity numeric(18,3),
    CONSTRAINT hourly_article_revenue_pkey PRIMARY KEY (outlet_id, article_name, plu, article_group_name, hour)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hourly_waiter_revenue
(
    hour timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL,
    outlet_id uuid NOT NULL,
    waiter_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    waiter_number character varying(10) NOT NULL,
    gross_revenue numeric(18,3),
    net_revenue numeric(18,3),
    CONSTRAINT hourly_waiter_revenue_pkey PRIMARY KEY (outlet_id, waiter_name, waiter_number, hour)
);

and others.
The application supports multi-tenancy which is based on the outlet_id discriminator column. Currently there are no plans for partitioning, but this may change.
I am trying to do performance benchmarking on certain types of planned queries which would take these preaggregated hourly facts and then additionally perform ad-hoc aggregations for non-specific time frames (i.e. days to months), and have run into issues with the current design regarding the bloat of multiple fact tables (e.g. highly bloated primary keys) which screams denormalization of dimensions.
The worst case scenario is for there to be entries in each of these fact tables for each over for up to 2 years - with around 50000 outlets this yields between 700M and several billions of rows for each "fact" table depending on any additional dimensions. The grain of these individual facts is always hourly.
To combat this, I believe I will need some degree of dimensional modeling to better support the types of queries that will be run (queries that impact <1day of data are rather trivial).
Taking the hourly_article_revenue fact table as an example, I would have done something like the following:

Extract the article dimension into a separate dim_article table, give it a surrogate ID.
Add a unique constraint over the current business definition over uniqueness: (outlet_id, article_name, plu, article_group_name).
Reference the dim_article surrogate key as a foreign key in the relevant fact table.

repeating this process for the rest of the tables and their dimensions (e.g. waiters).
However, this approach smells somewhat... off due to the fact that - theoretically, I only require one fact table which is sourced from the pre-aggregated data with the highest number of dimensions (and then just drill-up based on the specific requirements). For example, the following two queries sourced from different fact tables:
SELECT outlet_id, date_trunc('month', hour) 
FROM hourly_revenue
WHERE outlet_id = '...'

and:
SELECT outlet_id, date_trunc('month', hour) 
FROM hourly_article_revenue
WHERE outlet_id = '...'
GROUP BY outlet_id

are essentially semantically equivalent, at which point I may as well have just used the raw transaction facts (notwithstanding the near-realtime requirement of data freshness).
The obvious drawback is that I cannot necessarily know all the required dimensions beforehand, and as such the fact table would necessarily need to add more dimensions as time goes on, which would be a monumental maintenance burden as opposed to creating a new fact table pertaining to the dimensions that are relevant for those key insights given by a new ETL resultset.
Is there a more general approach for this kind of modeling with multiple "fact" tables? Do those principles still hold if the different fact tables are - essentially - drilled up versions of other fact tables?
Lastly: is there any further reading I can do on this topic? I have read Kimball et al but I do not have it near my person at the moment and so cannot reference it at this time to verify...

The terminology I was looking for in Kimball et al was aggregate fact tables, and from what I can tell it is an acceptable representation of dimensional modeling with regards to trading off query performance and storage footprint. So, it seems I wasn't completely off.

However, my initial design above makes very little use of surrogate keys for my dimensions/fact tables, and this is something I need to rework to support changing dimensions type 2, which is definitely something that will have an impact in our application.
